# Auto-indent with the same spaces and tabs as on previous line

Tags: notepad++, indentation, autoindent

I usually indent code files with two spaces, not the default in notepad++. That leads to the problem that if I type two indents, it gets converted to a tab, and then I have to delete it and type in its place two spaces.
The problem is that I can't just change the tab indentation length or turn it off at all, because I'm also working on a file which has strict tab-indentation rules.

My question is: Is there any way to make notepad++ indent a line with the same spacing as on the previous line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check Notepad++ plugin "TabIndentSpaceAlign": http://code.google.com/p/kereds-notepad-plus-plus-plugins/